# Difference between observations and variables in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, machine-learning

I'm kind of ashamed to even ask this but here goes. In every Matlab help file where the input matrix is a `NxD` matrix `X` Matlab describes the matrix arrangement as

> Data, specified as a numeric matrix. The rows of X correspond to
>   observations, and the columns correspond to variables.

Above taken from help of [kmeans](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#inputarg_X)

I'm kind of confused as to what does Matlab mean by observations and variables.

Suppose I have a data matrix composed of 100 images. Each image is represented by a feature vector of size `128 x 1`. So here is 100 my observations and 128 the variables or is it the other way around?

Will my data matrix be of the size `128 x 100` or `100 x 128`

Comment: 100 observations, 128 variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eugene's explanation in a statistical and probability construct is great, but I would like to explain it more in the viewpoint of data analysis and image processing.

Think of an observation as one **sample** from your data set.  In this case, one observation is one image.  For each sample, it has some dimensionality associated to it or a number of variables used to represent such a sample.

For example, if we had a set of 100 2D Cartesian points, the amount of **observations** is 100, while the dimensionality or the total number of **variables** used to describe the point is 2: We have a `x` point and a `y` point.  As such, in the MATLAB universe, we'd place all of these data points into a single matrix. Each **row** of the matrix denotes one point in your data set.  Therefore, the matrix you would create here is `100 x 2`.

Now, go back to your problem.  We have 100 images and each image can be expressed by 128 features.  This suspiciously looks like you are trying to use SIFT or SURF to represent an image so think of this situation where each image can be described by a 128-dimensional vector, or a histogram with bins of 128 elements.  Each feature is part of the dimensionality makeup that makes up the image.  Therefore, you would have a `100 x 128` matrix.  Each row represents **one image**, where each image is represented as a `1 x 128` feature vector.

In general, MATLAB's machine learning and data analysis algorithms assume that your matrix is `M x N`, where `M` is the total number of points that make up your data set while `N` is the dimensionality of one such point in your data set.  In MATLAB's universe, the total number of observations is equal to the total number of points in your data set, while the total number of features / distinct attributes to represent one sample is the total number of variables.

### `tl:dr`

- Observation: One sample from your data set
- Variable: One feature / attribute that helps describe an observation or sample in your data set.
- Number of observations: Total number of points in your data set
- Number of variables: Total number of features / attributes that make up an observation or sample in your data set.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderfully detailed answer. Yes you are right, these are SIFT features, but I had to bring the SIFT matrices to vectors by using RootSIFT. That is why all the SIFT vectors are 128 elements long. Suppose if I had 100 images and each image is represented by a matrix of size ``128 x 50``, how then would the input matrix be arranged in this case? Thank you

Comment: @FarazKhan - My pleasure :).  One common technique that people do is they **unroll** the matrix so that it becomes a single `128 x 50` vector.  People particularly do this when dealing with machine learning algorithms, like SVMs.  Therefore, you would have a matrix that becomes `100 x (128*50)`.  Take your matrix and do `matrix(:).'`.  This will unroll the matrix into a row vector.  `matrix(:)` transforms the matrix into a column vector, and we then transpose so it becomes a row vector.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are talking about some specific statistical/probabilistic functions. In statistics or probability theory there are some random variables that are results of some kind of measurements/observations over time (or some other dimension). So such a matrix is just a collection of N measurements of D different random variables.